# swift firebase search user results

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing a user search in the code below. The return value is user info and user setting. I just want to get only user info. Is this possible?

database model :

- users

  - userid

    - info

      -name

      -online
    - setting

      - openid
      - email

my code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild:"info/name").queryStarting(atValue: text , childKey:"name").queryEnding(atValue: text + "\u{f8ff}" , childKey: "name").queryLimited(toFirst: sonucSayısı)

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if value == text{
        print(snapshot)
    }
}) { (err) in
    print(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only filtering mechanism is queries, but that will give you a subset of the nodes directly under `users`.

There is no way to get a subset of each node. If that is required for your use-case, consider splitting your data in two top-level nodes (`/userinfos` and `/usersettings`), both using the UID as the key, and then loading it from the one node that is (or both nodes that are) relevant to the use-case.

Also see:

- [Firebase: How to structure public/private user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data)
- [Firebase security rules to read partial objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102092/firebase-security-rules-to-read-partial-objects)
- [Firebase realtime database: How to listen to a specific subset of items of a node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65663123/firebase-realtime-database-how-to-listen-to-a-specific-subset-of-items-of-a-nod/65670852)
- [Firebase Rules to read Specific Leaf / Child Node from Parent Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562214/firebase-rules-to-read-specific-leaf-child-node-from-parent-nodes)